# UITableView selected row load new view carrying variable over

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

I have a UITableView on my ViewController1. Upon selection it loads ViewController2, carrying a **variable (that i declared as "passedData")** bearing the name of the respective row selected over as well. In testing the workability of the code, i assigned "passedData" to a label on ViewController2 as such:

```
label.text = "passedData";
```

It works nicely. The list in my tableview in ViewController1 has rows loaded from an array with temporary naming convention:
Summary, report, detail etc.

So the idea is when "Summary" is selected, it would load ViewController2 which then loads another subview relating to SummaryViewController. In trying to let ViewController2 to recognize which view controller to sub load, i did this in `-(void) viewDidLoad:`

```
NSString *viewtoload = passedData;
    if (viewtoload == "Summary") {
        //Load summaryViewController
    }
    elseif (viewtoload == "Report") {
        //Load reportViewController
    }
    elseif (viewtoload == "Detail") {
        //Load detailViewController
    }
```

i got this error:

```
1. Implicit conversion of a non-objective-C pointer type 'char *' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC.
2. Result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead)
3. Comparison of distinct pointer types ('NSString *' and 'char *')
```

My questions are:

1) Is this a correct approach or is there a better method to this?

2) How do i resolve this error i got above?

3) What is the syntax to load another subview?

I thank you all in advance.

Comment: Need to learn basics first. 1. [Learn Objective-C](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/learn-objective-c-day-1/) 2. [The Basics of Objective-C](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Basics_of_Objective-C_Programming)

Comment: So do you have a UITableview with 3 cells. Summary, Report and Detail? When you tap on the cell you want it to load the correct View Controller?

Comment: Please don't significantly edit your question after you have answers, it makes the answers you already have unintelligible. If you have further questions create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load different View Controllers depending on what cell was tapped you should do this in your

```
//handle selections of cell in specified row and section of table view
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //switch row
    switch(indexPath.row)
    {

        case:0
        {
            //Detail row
            Detail01 *viewController = [[Detail01 alloc] init];
            viewController.somePassedInData = theDataToPass;
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
            break;
        }
        case:1
        {
            //Report row
            Report01 *viewController = [[Report01 alloc] init];
            viewController.somePassedInData = theDataToPass;
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
            break;
        }
        case:2
        {
            //Summary row
            //Alloc and init VC here
            Summary01 *viewController = [[Summary01 alloc] init];
            viewController.somePassedInData = theDataToPass;
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    //deselect table cell
    [_tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

You can then set any properties in the VC before you push onto the Navigation Controller

Comment: I used 'if' instead of case since i'm not familiar with 'case' approach. However the selected row did not load the new viewController...

Comment: Because when you get the section or row from the indexPath you get an int that you can call a switch on. A switch basically has cases, if the int you are checking in this case indexPath.section it looks for the cases and if a case matches the value it executes that code in that case until it hits a break; then comes out of the switch. If none of the cases match the code in the default case will be ran.

Comment: You can make your code far cleaner by using enums too. An enum is a textual representation of a number. http://speirs.org/blog/2008/10/11/a-technique-for-using-uitableview-and-retaining-your-sanity.html

Comment: I have updated my answer to follow what you want (To the best I can from the information you have given). Note that in each VC there should be a property of type whatever you want to pass to that VC. That property needs to be in the .h of your Class so it can be accessed outside of the new VC. You pass the data by setting that property then showing the view. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

use correct objective-c String literals `@""` instead of `""`

Comment: passedData is a variable passed from ViewController1